# Azure web job stopped/aborted

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have an azure web job running continuously, but the logs indicated that over the weekend it's status changed to Aborted, then Stopped. Although I did not use the website for the weekend, I am not sure why this would happen as there are still a lot of messages on the queue that need to be processed.

What can cause a continuous web job to stop or abort? 
Does it have a timeout period? 
Can the occurrence of multiple errors also cause it to stop or abort?

Comment: Which service is executing your "web job"? An azure web site?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson yes a website

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The job itself doesn't have a timeout period but the website does. Unless you enable the [Always On](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) option, the website (and the jobs) will unload after some idle time.

Another reason why a continuous job could stop is if you are running on the free tier and the job uses too much CPU time (I think you have 2.5 minutes CPU time for every 5 minutes).

Comment: Do Basic ans Standard modes also have a CPU time limitation?
I tried a long running webjob in both, and it's aborted after ~12h.
I put a 10 millisecond sleep in the main loop so it doesn't use all the CPU, would it help to put more? it would mean, the job runs longer. I have Always On turned on.

Comment: @atika check out this thread which helped me to solve the problem of automatically aborting long-running webjobs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939766/long-running-web-job-being-aborted-by-azure