# Long running Web Job being aborted by Azure

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a Web Job within an Azure website that is being aborted.
Its rather long running, taking perhaps 30 mins. It pulls in a lot of data from an Azure SQL database and basically compiles figures used for reporting.

Looking at the output logs it would appear that Azure aborts the job with no warning mid way through execution. There is no indication as to why.

Is there a way to prevent Azure from aborting a Web Job?

The website is hosted within a standard azure website.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have always on enabled?

Comment: nope! Is the issue that the process is being shut down due to the website itself being inactive?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci So this problem goes away if you enable Always On in the website configuration?

Answer (score 7):

Check the `stopping_wait_time` parameter within webjob-publish-settings.json. The value of the parameter is used in seconds. So if you need 30 minutes of execution time before azure aborts it use:

`"stopping_wait_time": 1800`

Credits here: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VNqThvmG8oc

regards

Comment: That website is unreachable for me at the moment, and I don't already hae a value for `"stopping_wait_time": ` - what is the default if no value is specified?

Comment: I am not sure, but in the test that I've done, it takes 5 five minutes before the job is stopped.

Comment: It is 5 seconds(!)