# Scheduled Webjob "hangs" on completion and fails to terminate by itself

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a web job that is successfully scheduled and running every 2 hours as I want it to.  Unfortunately it never completely terminates when it has finished running, just seems to hang there after the last statement in the code is executed.  Then after a while I get the following exception:-

> [07/27/2016 19:09:53 > 0e1e46: SYS ERR ] System.AggregateException:
>   One or more errors occurred. --->
>   Kudu.Core.Infrastructure.CommandLineException: Command 'cmd /c
>   ""AppName ...' was aborted due to no output nor CPU activity for 121
>   seconds. You can increase the SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT app setting (or
>   WEBJOBS_IDLE_TIMEOUT if this is a WebJob) if needed.

My code is as follows:-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for operation...");
        host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("ProcessBalances"));
        Console.WriteLine("Task completed.");
    }
}
```

The "ProcessBalances" function executes and then the "Task completed." is successfully displayed in the output.

There do not seem to be many actual code examples of a Scheduled web job out there.  Should I be using "Continuous" instead - as there are plenty of examples of those?

Comment: Does your 'Task completed' get printed to the output?

Comment: Thanks David - yes it does (see sentence after the code snippet).

Comment: Other thing to test: from Kudu Process Explorer, do you see your WebJob process still being up after it's supposed to have completed?

Comment: Not sure where that is, but I will take a look.  However my webjob takes 10-12 minutes to run and it looks to me that the process is present for 2 minutes after it has completed and then the Kudu.Core.Infrastructure "aborts" the process due to "inactivity".  The job overall is marked as "Running" before being moved to "Failed".  So from that I had concluded that yes, the process is still up after executing that last Writeln statement and it is the fact that it is "up" for 2 minutes that causes the Kudu.Core.Infrastructure to "abort" it?

Comment: Did you see this post with a similar problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23743599/azure-web-job-stopped-aborted

Comment: Thanks but I don't believe it is that. My code has completed but doesn't exit correctly. That is why 2 mins later the timeout kicks in. But the code has completed and the timeout is correct, it's just that my code is not exiting correctly somehow?  Should it return a value?

Comment: In my case the problem was a Console.ReadLine(); for debugging purposes

Comment: @PaulR did you end up addressing this issue?